# Why can't I resolve conflicts in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The "accept current" and the "accept incoming" actions are not visible in my code editor[image]

Comment: You first need to remove those merge conflicts. Right now that file is "broken" until you remove any "<<<<<<<<< HEAD" and the other "=========="

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla That's what they're talking about. VS Code typically presents buttons that do this for you.

Comment: Maybe change the photo i see userlogin token at the bottom.

Comment: @sweenish the picture posted is different now. As the entire class was marking errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after the new 3-way merge was enabled by default in v1.70. The new merge wasn't starting but it also disabled the old one.

Try setting `git.mergeEditor` settings to `false`, or unchecking **Git: Merge Editor** setting in the Settings UI.

[image]

Note that you may need to reopen the file to see the changes.